# Combining multiple tables with uncommon columns

Tags: sql, oracle

How can i get my expected output. I join first two tables by Left Outer Join, but as soon as i join the third one my expected result goes away.

[image]

Comment: Show us your query attempt.

Comment: @jarlh `SELECT T1.ORDER_CODE, T1.ORDER_ITEM, T1.CUSTOMER NAME, T2.RUN_NO, T4.BLOCK_NO
FROM TABLE T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE T2 ON T1.ORDER_CODE = T2.ORDER_CODE AND T1.ORDER_ITEM = T2.ORDER_ITEM
INNER JOIN TABLE T3 ON T2.RUN_NO = T3.RUN_NO
INNER JOIN TABLE T4 ON T3.BLOCK_NO = T4.BLOCK_NO`

Comment: Please don't put additional information as comment, edit your question for this.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit 1. No one should be editing the question after posting because the new comers on the post respond to the post as per the latest comments, if i keep changing the post it'll create a confusion. 2. I didnt put any extra info, just provided the query which i tried myself to the user who asked

Comment: The query is an essential information for your question, so it should be part of your question - that's the reason for the down votes you got.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit noted for future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `left join`s:

```
select 
    t1.*,
    t2.runno,
    t3.blockno,
    t4.quantity
from t1
left join t2 
    on t2.ordercode = t1.ordercode and t2.orderitem = t1.orderitem
left join t3
    on t3.runno = t2.runno
left join t4
    on t4.blockno = t3.blockno
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didnt tried left Outer join earlier.